# Add OpenCV to path of Anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

Im running ubuntu, and using the Anaconda distribution of Python.  I am trying to ge the latest version of openCV (3.1.0) running, and i have cloned it from github to my computer.

However, it seems to only be on the system Python rather than the anaconda version i am using.

While i am aware that i can use

```
    conda install opencv
```

The version is only 2.4.1.

How can i modify the PYTHONPATH so that the latest version i cloned is used?
I've tried using

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/home/myname/opencv')
```

But this doesn't change anything.